# Not getting post value of textarea when using TinyMCE

Tags: php, jquery, html, tinymce

Im using TinyMCE here is my code :-

```
 tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced"
});
```

and here is my html code:-

```
<textarea name="terms" id="elm1"  rows="15" cols="30" width="100%" ></textarea>
```

the problem is that im not getting a post value of this textarea when im doing something like this :-

```
print_r($_POST['terms']);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the tinyMCE documentation to see if there is a method you need to run to populate the textarea with the value from the tinyMCE? (most RTE's that I have worked with have such a method)

Comment: where do you do `print_r($_POST['term']);` after submit or what ?

Comment: @mgraph yes im doing that after submit

Comment: :) did you written <form method="post"> to send the data to post array?

Comment: then you are providing too little information to help you. post all your form code.

Comment: Surely the problem is the name of the textarea is terms and you're printing term?

Comment: sorry for that but i edited my question...

Comment: In that case there is nothing in your code that is wrong. You need to post more to get help.

Comment: If you are posting using AJAX, you muse call `tinyMCE.get('nameoftextarea');` to populate the textarea with the contents of tinyMCE. http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/ajax_load_save.php

Comment: @KevinB im not posting using AJAX

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you need to call `tinymce.triggerSave()` right before you submit your form.

Comment: im not using ajax form...im submitting the form normally.its not working for me

Comment: then use the following before you submit your form:  $('#elm1').html(tinymce.get('elm1').getContent());